# TTThumbsViewController not show thumbnails when using stylesheet.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

If I use global stylesheet ( `[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[StyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];` ) than I don't see any thumbnails in `TTThumbsViewController`.

I specify these styles for `TTThumbsViewController`:

```
- (UIColor *)navigationBarTintColor;
- (UIColor *)backgroundColor;
- (UIColor *)tablePlainBackgroundColor;
- (UIColor *)tableHeaderTintColor;
- (UIColor *)thumbnailBackgroundColor;
```

If I set `thumbnailBackgroundColor` to `grayColor` I see gray rectangles in the controller but no downloaded images.

If I comment use of global stylesheet I see thumbnails correctly.

I tried use stylesheet in `TTControl` demo app and `TTThumbsViewController` behave same as in my app.

Here is screenshot from `TTControl` demo app:

[image]

I hope I am not doing something wrong. Can anybody have some idea why this is happening ?
Thanks. Bye.

Comment: I just edited my TTCatalog sample app to use my TTDefaultStyleSheet class and I don't have any problems. See http://cl.ly/75vm 
Where do you set your Style (in which file) ?
Maybe you just have to upgrade to the newest version of Three20.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Tutorial to help you with implementing `TTStyleSheet` properly:

[Three20 Stylesheets iPhone Tutorial](http://mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial)